# SWT TreeViewer expand and collaps at the same time when SWT.FULL_SELECTION is set

Tags: java, treeview, swt, jface

I have implemented a TreeViewer as followed and added a double click listener to it. This double click listener is supposed to expand/collapse a node.

```
treeViewer = new TreeViewer(component, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI );
treeViewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {
            public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent e) {
                final IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) e
                        .getSelection();
                if (selection == null || selection.isEmpty())
                    return;

                final Object sel = selection.getFirstElement();
                TreeNode selNode = (TreeNode) sel;

                if (treeViewer.getExpandedState(sel)) {
                    treeViewer.collapseToLevel(sel, 1);
                } else {
                    treeViewer.expandToLevel(sel, 1);
                }
            }
        });
```

Now if I change the TreeViewer to be FULL_SELECTION like...

```
treeViewer = new TreeViewer(component, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
```

this behavoiur changes to something weird.

When double clicked on the node where the lable is displayed, everything works as previous. BUT when clicked on the row, a little further away from the lable the node get's expanded/collapsed both at the same time, making no change at all.

Debugging it I found, that before the double click event I receive there is another event fired (or sth is listening to it before I get to deal with it), expanding/collapsing the specific node. Disabling the listener I was able to get rid of that behaviour. But that again disabled the expansion of the node when double clicked on the lable.

I have seen similar behavior in eclipse while debugging and wondered whether this is a know bug or even worse intended behaviour?

Any suggestions are appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can observe the issue that you describe on Windows 7. This *something* that expands/collapses an item is most likely native code.

While I think this is a bug in SWT or the Win32 tree control that [should be reported](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform) and fixed or worked around in SWT, I found a workaround that works on first sight. If you use an SWT listener on the `Tree` widget instead of the `IDoubleClikListener` you can determine if the label itself was clicked or just the *row* and expand/collapse the item yourself or leave it to that *something*.

```
treeViewer.getTree().addListener( SWT.DefaultSelection, new Listener() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
    TreeItem treeItem = ( TreeItem )event.item;
    Point cursorLocation = event.display.getCursorLocation();
    Point localCursorLocation = treeItem.getParent().toControl( cursorLocation );
    if( treeItem.getBounds().contains( localCursorLocation ) ) {
      // put your JFace expand/collapse code here
    }
  }
} );
```

Since this issue is likely platform dependant you should test on all targeted platforms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I was messing around with the idea myself, but couldn't figure out how to get my hands on whether the label or the row was clicked. +1 for that.
I will check further into this in the next days, but for now I will mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: I tested your code and it works for me. I only had to modify `treeItem.getBounds(int Index)` to `treeItem.getBounds()` in order to get it to work with multi-column trees.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated the answer accordingly.